# PostSharp Instrumentation for Multiple DLLs

Tags: c#, postsharp

I came across a post to instrument a dll if we do not have access to the source code, It had the following steps,

Generate postsharp.config with the following content:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.postsharp.org/1.0/configuration">
<Property Name="Input" Value="ClassLibrary2.dll" />
<Property Name="Output" Value="ClassLibrary2.Instrumented.dll" />
<SearchPath Path="C:\MyAspects" />
<Multicast>
<LogExecutionTimeAttribute xmlns="clr-namespace:MyAspectsNS;assembly:MyAspects" />
</Multicast>
</Project>
```

Execute tools\postsharp-net40-x86-native.exe postsharp.config. (This executable is found in the ZIP package from PostSharp)

It is working perfectly fine but I wanted to instrument multiple dlls in my bin folder, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As answered at https://support.postsharp.net/request/27365-instrumenting-multiple-dlls :

> This feature is no longer supported in current versions of PostSharp. PostSharp 5.44.0 *(the version used by @Tasheer Hussain)* is no longer supported either. So, if you keep using this feature, we *(the PostSharp team)* cannot guarantee to be of help if you get into any troubles.
>
> One way to process multiple assemblies could be to remove the Input and Output properties from the configuration file and pass them as arguments into the PostSharp compiler. You'd then execute the compiler multiple times using a script having just one configuration file. The command would look like:
>
> `tools\postsharp-net40-x64-native.exe postsharp.config /p:Input=ClassLibrary2.dll /p:Output=ClassLibrary2.Instrumented.dll`